# Externally hosted form and NetSuite Data

Tags: netsuite

I have a page hosted on an external site and I would like to create a form on that page. The use of the form would be to collect data to create SO in Netsuite.

In the form itself, I would like to have an autopopulate functionality so that for e.g. when I put in "Kat" in End User contact, I see all contacts starting with "Kat". This will enable me to select a correct contact and also help prevent duplication of data. Can you please guide me on how to structure this flow. What Netsuite components should i be using? For the external site, it will use Django.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a couple of RESTlets in NetSuite. One to perform a search to get the contacts and return them in the payload, and one to create sales order in NetSuite and populate it with the values provided in the payload.

How are you solving the issue with CORS?

Comment: I am using Django and I can do cors exempt.any other suggestions ?

Comment: What is wrong with the suggestions above? You need to create two RESTlets, one that will generate the JSON needed for the type-ahead functionality (or search functionality, whatever you like to call it) and one to submit the page to NetSuite and generate the sales order.